# Angular producing multiple duplicated inline styles

Tags: css, angular, webpack, angular-cli

running into a bit of a problem with my web apps styles that I was hoping to get some insight on. I have a simple site that I created for my students, everything works fine but I noticed some duplicated styles in the page source when I run ng serve and or run a build with prod.

[image]

All the styles are duplicated and I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. I tried various solutions and can't seem to find a solution that works out of the box. **The only way I got rid of the duplicated styles was to import everything into the styles.css and not use the styleUrls: ["./nameof.component.scss"] in the components**.

The strange thing is that when I look at the contents of the index.html file after a build in my editor those style tags are not in there. I understand this is a pretty loaded question especially without a plunker or example which unfortunatley I can not provide. Any ideas/assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**Architecture overview**

**_base.scss** which contains the following imports that are all scss partials I just left out the underscore in the import name as from what I understand is best practice/norm:

```
@import "variables";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "mixins";
```

**styles.css** this is not a partial and imports the base which is a partial like so:

```
@import "base";
```

**All of my components that make up the site also import _base.scss as I need to utilize various things such as variables, functions and bootstrap grid mixins etc..**

**In the angular config file** I have the following in the architect object in the styles array:

```
"styles": [
  "src/scss/styles.scss"
]
```

**In the same config file** in the configuration object I have the following:

```
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "buildOptimizer": true
        }
      }
```